# antlr4 compile error: Serialized ATN data element out of range

Tags: java, antlr

antlr4.5, target Java, jdk1.6.

I compiled a `.g4` combined file, and got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Serialized ATN data element out of range.
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATNSerializer.serialize(ATNSerializer.java:370)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATNSerializer.getSerialized(ATNSerializer.java:547)
at org.antlr.v4.codegen.model.SerializedATN.<init>(SerializedATN.java:46)
at org.antlr.v4.codegen.model.Recognizer.<init>(Recognizer.java:87)
at org.antlr.v4.codegen.model.Lexer.<init>(Lexer.java:51)
at org.antlr.v4.codegen.OutputModelController.lexer(OutputModelController.java:176)
at org.antlr.v4.codegen.OutputModelController.buildLexerOutputModel(OutputModelController.java:129)
at org.antlr.v4.codegen.CodeGenerator.generateLexer(CodeGenerator.java:144)
at org.antlr.v4.codegen.CodeGenPipeline.process(CodeGenPipeline.java:73)
at org.antlr.v4.Tool.processNonCombinedGrammar(Tool.java:429)
at org.antlr.v4.Tool.process(Tool.java:379)
at org.antlr.v4.Tool.processGrammarsOnCommandLine(Tool.java:346)
at org.antlr.v4.Tool.main(Tool.java:193)
at com.dicp.fdsl.antlr.FDSLCompiler.main(FDSLCompiler.java:13)
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: Same situation as yours and just filed a bug at the project page in GitHub: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/840

Comment: ths a lot. I'll upgrade it and then have a try.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, so I began commenting out lines in my grammar until the error went away.

In my case, the problem was a typo in my rules for numeric literals:

fragment DIGIT : '0'..'9 ' ;

Changing that to either of the following made the error go away:

fragment DIGIT : '0'..'9' ;

fragment DIGIT : [0123456789] ;

It seems likely that the character range from '0' to '9 ' is interpreted as Unicode values, and it produces an unexpectedly large range. This is consistent with the discussion in the ANTLR group at https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/840.